# How to use a Dictionary in VBA to transfer data from a Table to a Worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I am building an Excel application that takes data from an "Employee Data Table" and transfers it to a "Coaching Form".

The Coaching Form is created if an employee id match exists. The struggle I am facing is transferring the data from the Employee Data Table to nearly 200+ named ranges on the Coaching Form.

Not all the columns of data are being used, and they are not organized to follow the coaching form structure.

> **Example**

**Data table**: "employee_ID"

**Coaching Form**: `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("EmployeeID_Field").value = employee_ID`

**Data table**: "employee_Office"

**Coaching Form**: `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("EmployeeOffice_Field").value = employee_Office`

(...*and so on*)

> **Coaching Form Layout**
>   Header, Body, Footer

- Header - Contains over 10 named ranges
- Body - Contains over 100 named ranges
- Footer - Contains over 50 named ranges

> **Employee Data Table Layout**
>   3,000+ Rows, 30+ plus columns

**Possible Dictionary Solution**

*Dictionary 1*

Using a loop, store each header value I will be using from the Employee Data Table as my `*Key*`, and saving the data from the matching Employee ID record as the `*Value*`

How can I implement a second `Dictionary` to merge the data from `employee_ID` `key` to equal the value of `EmployeeID_Field` `key` in a second Dictionary?

[image]

> **Coaching Form shows named ranges in yellow**

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a good approach might be to create a mapping table of data table Column Name to named range name, and use that to drive the code which transfers values.

Comment: @Tim Williams are you saying to create a separate named range say, "TableHeaderRange" to list all the headers I am using from my Employee Data Table? Can I still use a dictionary approach going that route?

Comment: You can use a dictionary - did you try that already and run into problems?  It's not exactly clear from your question what the source data looks like, but why not just make a start and see where you get?

Comment: @Tim Williams, I'll write something up in a bit, I'll be editing my question to include my code.